# cannot set timezone in migrate CI3

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone, continuous-integration

I want to create migration file automatically in Codeigniter 3. The problem is when I generate file name with timestamp, I use `date_default_timezone_set` like this below code, but it doesn't work. I tried to use similar construct in other controllers and they work very well. I had tried other ways such as set timezone in index.php or config file but they didn't work, too. What am I missing?

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migrate extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh');

    if ( !$this->input->is_cli_request() ) {
        show_error('You don\'t have permission for this action', 403);
        return;
    }
    $this->load->library('migration');
}

public function generate($name = false)
{
    if ($name === false) {
        echo 'Please define migration name' . PHP_EOL;
        return;
    }
    if ( !preg_match('/^[a-z_]+$/i', $name) ) {
        echo 'File name must contain only a-z characters' . PHP_EOL;
        return;
    }

    var_dump(ini_get('date.timezone')); // see set timezone here
    $fileName = sprintf('%d_%s.php', date('YmdHis'), $name);
    try {
        $folderPath = APPPATH . 'migrations/';
        if ( !is_dir($folderPath) ) {
            try {
                mkdir($folderPath);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error on create folder: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

        $filePath = $folderPath . $fileName;
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            echo 'File already exists' . PHP_EOL;
            return;
        }

        $data['className'] = $name;
        $data = '<?php ' . $this->load->view('migrations/migration-template', $data, true);

        try {
            if(file_put_contents($filePath, $data) !== false)
                echo 'Migration file was created successfully' . PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "but it doesn't work". That isn't helpful. What input? What expected output? What actual output? What error_log warnings errors or notices are there?

Comment: Sorry for not clear description. I used `var_dump(ini_get('date.timezone')); // see set timezone here` to see what set timezone is: 'Europe/Berlin', it's not Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh as my exspectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the set command you use works for that script only and doesn't alter the ini. So, by grabbing the ini value, you now have non matching timezones.

Instead, use `date_default_timezone_get()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Or use both `ini_set()` and `ini_get()`.

Below code is from the set manual page https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
    echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
```

So, to sum up, don't mix the two functionalities together!

Comment: Thank you! I use `date_default_timezone_get` and it works

Comment: Glad I could help, can you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Yeah, I did it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Load the timezone in the config/autoload.php file at the top of the page.

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');